# access local folder from Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

I was wondering if permission needs to be set manually or in a program in order to access a local folder? My Windows Store app needs to read a file on the same machine, and in another drive/folder. My Windows Store app will process and display the local data using C#.

Comment: Does this help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readlinesasync(v=win.10).aspx

Comment: I'm curious myself about the answer to this question. I do Android apps, and researching possibility to port to Windows Store app, looked into this issue briefly. It seemed to me that in order to read a file beyond the local app storage, the file "handle" or whatever it is, must have been obtained from Microsoft file chooser control - no way to access a file or folder outside app local storage with just the path and file name...

Comment: @Jacobr365, thanks and vote up! I see you are referring some APIs, want to confirm with you using such kinds of API could access folder and files outside Window Store App? Even without higher privilege/permission?

Comment: That I am not sure about. You could give it a shot. You may want to read up on file access permissions for Windows store apps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#locations-windows-store-apps-can-access

Comment: Thanks @Jacobr365, I am reading the first link you referred, for API ReadLinesAsync. From the MSDN page, I do not find it is for Windows Store app? It is said for Windows Phone, Windows 8 and Windows server? Appreciate if you could confirm as well. :)

Comment: Can't confirm 100% as I have not tried it myself but that pages leads back to a page about developing apps so I would assume that it should work. Once again the best way to find out is to just try it. Worst case is you get an access denied error or something similar.

Comment: Thanks @Jacobr365, vote up and will try and let you know. One more basic question, I am a bit confused in your 2nd link, it is mentioned, "user's Downloads folder", what means "user" here? If I run as administrator, the user is administrator? Thanks. :)

Comment: Downloads folder in that context is 'C:\Users\your name\Downloads'

Comment: Thanks @Jacobr365, does it mean login user name? If so, I just login as administrator and should have super permission for all folders? :)

Comment: No, sadly you logging in as admin does not give your program the same admin rights. they mean the person using your app. If the whole point is to make a win store app you wont be the end user, the ones downloading it are. So you can not log in as anything. They are talking about the Downloads folder as in the the place files go when you download them from the web.

Comment: @Jacobr365, nice explain and vote up. :)

My short term needs is to show a demo to others on the Windows Store app for functionalities, I do not need to demo download by other users and it might even be used for admin users only in the future. In this case, I think I can login as admin and run the Windows store app locally as admin? Then it should have super all folder permissions? :)

Comment: Sorry, you are now getting outside the scope of my knowledge. Based on the second link I would say that as long as you use a FilePicker or capabilities defined in the app manifest you should be able to gain access to whatever folders/files you want.

Comment: @Jacobr365, also a good idea. Vote up. Will try and let you know. :)

Comment: @Jacobr365, could you add a reply? I will mark it as answered to benefit other people. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments.
Links referenced: [file functions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileio.readlinesasync(v=win.10).aspx)

[File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#locations-windows-store-apps-can-access)

Comment: Thanks Jacobr365, mark your reply as answer. Have a good weekend. :)